# How can I forward a query string using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I am using this, at present, to rewrite URLS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/?\.]+)$ /page.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

So `mysite.com/home` gets rewritten to `mysite.com/page.php?name=home`

How can I make it also rewrite `mysite.com/home?param=value` to `mysite.com/page.php?name=home&param=value`? Ideally, I'd like this to work for any name/value querystring pairs.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "capturing variables" section at http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

It says that if you add [QSA] to the end of the rewrite rule, it should pass variables through the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

This made it work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/?\.]+)$ /page.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
```