# .htaccess rewrite pretty urls that can still use get variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, get

I'm trying to write an .htaccess line that will rewrite to a php script but still allow any extra get variables to be added on the end. Is this possible?

Currently I'm trying to use this:

```
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]*)([^/]*)$ /item.php?id=$1&$2 [L]
```

The aim is to be able to do things like `blah.com/item/foo`, but also `blah.com/item/foo?bar=whatever`.

Currently it seems to correctly pass the first part, `id`, but not the rest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I forward a query string using htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024316/how-can-i-forward-a-query-string-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]*)([^/]*)$ /item.php?id=$1&$2 [L,QSA]
```

You can read more about `QSA` (query string append) here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 5):

You need to finish with `[L,QSA]`