# AJAX sends values but wasn't able to retrieve in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm trying to pass the values from the link and use $_GET to receive the values. I've tried this on my local it works, but when I transferred it to a live site It won't receive the values of the parameters.

I've tried using firebug I can see the values are being stored in the link. But unable to $_GET them.

AJAX

```
function getDivUpdate(val) {

    var group = $("#grp").val();
    var div   = $("#div").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?=base_url()?>personnel/get_division_update/",
            data:{"group": group, "div": div},
            success: function(data){
                $('#div1').html(data);
             }
        }); 
}
```

PHP

```
function get_division_update($val=NULL){

            if(isset($_GET['group'])){  
            $select = "d_divname,dr_division";
            $table = "tbl_division";
            $where = "dr_group = $_GET[group]";
            $join1 = "tbl_division_rel";
            $join2 = "d_id = dr_division";

            echo "<select class='fieldnames' id='div' name='div'>";
            echo "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
            $division = $this -> Main -> select_data($select, $table, $where, $join1, $join2);
            foreach($division as $div){


                echo '<option value="'.$div['dr_division'].'"'; 
                if($div['dr_division'] == $_GET['div'])
                    { echo "selected=selected"; } echo ">"; 
                echo htmlspecialchars($div['d_divname']).'</option>';       

            }

            }

            else if(isset($_GET['div']) OR isset($_GET['group'])){

            $table="tbl_division";
            $select="*";
            $orderby="d_divname";
            $divs = $this -> Main -> dropdown_orderby($select, $table, $orderby);

            echo "<select class='fieldnames' id='div' name='div'>";
            echo "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
            foreach($divs as $d){
                echo "<option value='".$d['d_id']."'>".$d['d_divname']."</option>";
            }

            }

            else if(!isset($_GET['div']) AND !isset($_GET['group'])){


            $table="tbl_division";
            $select="*";
            $orderby="d_divname";
            $divs = $this -> Main -> dropdown_orderby($select, $table, $orderby);

            echo "<select class='fieldnames' id='div' name='div'>";
            echo "<option value=''>--Select3--</option>";
            foreach($divs as $d){

                echo "<option value='".$d['d_id']."'>".$d['d_divname']."</option>";
            }


            }
        }
```

Comment: `<?=` is the server short tags enabled?

Comment: Are you sure about `.val()`. Have you tried `.text()`?

Comment: try to alert(data); and see what you will got or use error: function(){}

Comment: @Dagon it is enabled.
@Roamer-1888 I've only tried `.val()` cause it gets the id in the Select option

Comment: OK, I was confused by the `<select>` element having `id=div`.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: @Terminus this is what I got `array(1) { ["/personnel/get_division_update/11"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: Sounds like you use something to make your urls "pretty". Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164992/htaccess-rewrite-pretty-urls-that-can-still-use-get-variables and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024316/how-can-i-forward-a-query-string-using-htaccess

Comment: @Terminus this is what is in my code 
`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`
could you suggest on what will I replace it with?

Comment: Well I don't have any experience with mod_rewrite but from looking at the questions linked, you need to add the QSA flag.

Answer (score 0):

Is the request truly success, cause you need to echo out base url for getting path as `base_url()` are returned the value, not printed the value, try change to below code :

```
url: "<?= echo base_url()?>personnel/get_division_update/", 
// or
url: "<?= echo base_url('personnel/get_division_update/')?>",
```

Comment: It may even be as simple as `url: "/personnel/get_division_update/",` given that the browser will assume the same protocol and domain as the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. I just changed the uri protocol of my codeigniter

FROM

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

TO

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```